# Where to find iconv.h on ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: rubygems, ubuntu-14.04

I'm attempting to build a ruby project that depends on tiny_tds 0.6.3.rc1, which fails when attempting to build the native gem.

`gem install tiny_tds -v '0.6.3.rc1'` fails with a helpful looking section that reads as follows:

```
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing tiny_tds:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /home/deploy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.7/bin/ruby -r ./siteconf20151202-9469-rxbbcc.rb extconf.rb
checking for iconv_open() in iconv.h... *** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.
```

The message is pretty clear, I need iconv.h, which I'd usually just install via `sudo apt-get install libiconv`, only it seems that libiconv isn't a think that exists for ubuntu 14.04.

Have I bumped up against a missing package, or is there something simpler I'm missing?

[edit]
`sudo apt-get install libiconv-dev` comes back with `E: Unable to locate package libiconv-dev`

A brief search of the package repository indicates that it doesn't seem to exist:

```
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS
Release:    14.04
Codename:   trusty

$ apt-cache search libiconv
librecode0 - Shared library on which recode is based
recode - Character set conversion utility
cl-babel - A charset encoding/decoding library, not unlike GNU libiconv
enca - Extremely Naive Charset Analyser - binaries
libiconv-hook-dev - header files of libiconv-hook
libiconv-hook1 - extension of iconv for libapache-mod-encoding
```

Comment: There should also be a `-dev` package that will contain the header. The non dev package does only contain the lib.

Comment: Thanks for the attempt @t.niese - Sadly it seems I'm out of luck. More google searching reveals that I may simply need to just download the source from the gnu org site and install it manually.

Comment: Did you install `sudo apt-get install build-essentials` ?

Comment: @t.niese build-essentials got installed pretty early on in the process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The root of the issue comes down to building tiny_tds 0.6.3.rc1. Version 0.7.0 includes a bit of magic to fetch the libiconv source, and build the library itself. In this case the fix was to upgrade the version of tiny_tds my project used through some creative dependency management.

Long story short, libiconv isn't available via aptitude in ubuntu 14.04.